# How to set grid's first column to fit available space after all another columns have taken required width?

Tags: wpf

I have a grid with three columns. I need the column's widths to be calculated in the following scenario:

> 1.Second and third columns are taking required width from the grid (for simplicity impliying that сolumn2.width + column3.width are
> always smaller than grid.Width).
>
> 2.After that first column is taking all available width left by 2nd and 3st columns (i.e. col1 = grid.width - (col2.Width + col3.W)).

Also, if first column's text can't fit to its width it should be wrapped (i.e. text should grow in height to display it's content).

[image: click to zoom]

I tried following

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:DiagramDataList}">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataElementList}"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                              Background="Transparent"
                              Focusable="False"
                              IsHitTestVisible="False"
                              BorderThickness="0"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                       
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentValue}"
                                               Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Difference}"
                                               Grid.Column="2"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                               Background="{Binding HtmlColor, Converter={StaticResource HtmlColorToColorConverter}}"
                                               Visibility="{Binding Path=Difference, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I think you should use `Width="Auto"` for the `column2` and `column3` to make it fit to the content, then use `Width="*"` for the `column1` for it to get all the remaining space.

Comment: @Bolu, you are right. Also I switched to DataGrid to make row auto-aligned.  Not all my requirements are done, but i'm working on it.

Answer (score 2):

Column's Width can take following values,
**1.Number**
Fixed size.
**2.Auto**
Column width=width of cell content.
**3.*(Star/Asterisk)**
Column width=available space in the grid.
Following code will give desired output,

```
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

You can have a number instead of "Auto" to keep those column size fixed.